# React MUI Chip onDelete access to stopPropagation method

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have a Chip like:

```js
  const onDelete = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // e.nativeEvent.stopPropagation();
  };
  return (
    <Chip
      label={name}
      sx={sx}
      component={NavLink}
      to={to}
      clickable={true}
      onDelete={onDelete}
    />);
```

None of the calls `stopPropagation()` worked, because they are undefined on the Event sent by **MUI** to the `onDelete` callback.

Is there anyway I can prevent this chip to follow the Link in `to` attribute if user clicked to Delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stopPropagation()` prevents further propagation of the current event but redirecting to  links are still processed. If you want to stop those behaviors,
you can use `preventDefault()` method :

```
const onDelete = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // e.nativeEvent.stopPropagation();
  };
```

Comment: hey, your answer is incorrect. in MUI Chip, `onDelete` i raised when user clicks to the Delete Icon. The point of `stopPropagation` here is to avoid the mouse click event to be propagated to the Link, which will provoke the redirect to the new page. Also, if you check the event sent by MUI to the onDelete callback, you'll notice that `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation` are undefined.

Comment: I tried   `console.log(e.preventDefault)`  on the **onDelete** function . actually it is defined it shows  `ƒ () {
          this.defaultPrevented = true;
          var event = this.nativeEvent;

          if (!event) {
            return;
          }

          if (event.preventDefault) {
            event.…`

Comment: you are right, I only checked the stopPropagation.
Thank you, it is working!!!

Comment: sure ! happy to help